# Problems hiding a page for explorer 10

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, internet-explorer-10

I am developing a website and ending with the graphical interface that it detected that it was not displayed correctly in the explorer 11. With css fix the problem. But it is poorly displayed in later versions of explorer. I made use of a hack <! - [if lt IE 11]> <! [Endif] -> so that from 10 it was not seen. and what is inside the hack keys will be displayed. That case works for me for all versions except for the 10 that the web is displayed with design errors.

It is assumed that by activating the data-useragent from js I can detect that the browser is ie 10 and modify the css but I have tried to emulate IE 10 from various sources (IE development tools, online emulator (netrenderer) and ietester (desktop application)) and since neither allows me to use JS I use jQuery.

As for the hack I have tried the different conditionals (lt gt!) To see if it takes version 10 but does not do it in any case.

Two known pages (pencode.com, twitter) crash the browser. But both when the tests in the different emulators have different behavior.

Could it be blocked from the server?

Thank you and sorry for the billet. I am somewhat blocked. I cannot put the url because it is in development.

Comment: Change the url **http://netrenderer.com/index .php** to **http://netrenderer.com/index.php**. There is a space between index and .php.

Comment: Conditional comments (the `<!-- [if IE xx...`) are not supported in IE 10-11. You could possibly detect IE 10 via UserAgent as you suggest. A better solution may be to share with us what the design error is and we can look at that.

Comment: Do you want to use IE-only stylesheet? Conditional comments are not supported in Internet Explorer 10 and 11. You can detect IE 10 using `window.navigator.userAgent`.